# how make changes with python code to other python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
name = input("what's your name?")
if name == "John"
#it will make changes to another code
with open('example.py') as f:
    f.write("John")
```

example.py before:

```
names = "Jack"
```

example.py after:

```
names = "Jack", "John"
```

So i want insert name to other python file with python code
how can i?

Comment: why not just have the example file read the names from a file?

Comment: That's also a nice approach. You could alternatively simply keep it updated on the code execution, as per your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is somewhat on the line, however there's a more pythonic way to do it:

```
>>> main.py
import example # example.py
name = input("what's your name?")
if name == "John":
    example.names.append(name) # append John
```

```
>>> example.py
names = ["Jack"]
```

*Note: This approach saves the variables until the code is executed.*
However, if you want permanent changes:

- Create another `names.txt` file

```
>>> main.py
name = input("what's your name?")
if name == "John":
    with open("names.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(f", {name}")
```

```
>>> names.txt
Jack, John
```

```
>>> example.py
with open("names.txt","r") as f:
    names = f.read().split(', ')
```

Comment: can i ask similar question about discord.py I want make if :catch command is used it will add random str to names.txt

Answer (score -1):

you have to add ,'w' to the open method to be able to write in it

`with open('example.py', 'w') as f:`

then you can do something like this

```
    
file = open('example.py', "r")
filecontents = ""
for line in file:
    change = ""
    if("names = " in line):
        change = line.strip() + ',"jhon"'

    filecontents += change + "\n"
    
file.close()
write_file = open("example.py", "w")
write_file.write(filecontents)
write_file.close()
```

Comment: This would just remove everything present in `example.py` and change it to `"John"`. Totally invalid.

Comment: yes it would, but it doesn't have to
I have made an edit to my awnser that shows the general idea